# I want to say that beer in heaven is free not that I'm speaking of our God in heaven but not sure where to place my comma. Please help!

Tags: punctuation

"Cheers to you, cheers to me, Thank God, in heaven beer is free!"
    or
"Cheers to you, cheers to me, Thank God in heaven, beer is free!"

Comment: In heaven there ain't no beer.  That's why we drink it here.

Comment: If you are saying that the beer that is in heaven is free, then your first option is what you want.

Comment: "Thank God, in heaven beer is free!" would be understood to mean that in the Hereafter, beer is free (to saved souls, angels, etc) in heaven.  "Thank God in heaven, beer is free!" would be understood to mean that beer Here Below is free--which, alas! is not often the case.

Comment: The comma separates ideas; put the comma where it makes those ideas clear.

Comment: @HotLicks The penultimate verse of [John Connoly's song Fiddler's Green](https://mainlynorfolk.info/steeleye.span/songs/fiddlersgreen.html) says "...the girls are all pretty and the beer is all free..." so there's free beer in the Grimsby fishermen's heaven! By the way, in spite of many rumours to the contrary this song is not traditional, it was written in 1966 and John is still very much alive, so it's not even out of copyright.

Comment: @BoldBen - 1956 - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_Heaven_There_Is_No_Beer

Comment: @HotLicks Maybe there's no German beer in heaven?

Comment: @BoldBen - Could be, but you'd think that would cause [Tears in Heaven](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/ericclapton/tearsinheaven.html).

Comment: @HotLicks Respect! To be boring I suppose there would be no beer in the Muslim, Salvation Army or old style Methodist heavens but I have difficulty imagining an Irish Catholic heaven without Guinness!

Answer (score -1):

You need to get rid of the capital letter T after the first comma, because a capital letter indicates the start of a new sentence.  Here is a suggestion:

"Cheers to you, cheers to me; thank God, in heaven beer is free!"

If you are starting a new sentence, then you need a full stop:

"Cheers to you, cheers to me. Thank God, in heaven beer is free!"

Either way, the comma goes after God.

Does the same principle apply to wine?